# Multithreading segmentation fault (for loop)

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector, segmentation-fault

Why does the following code give me a segmentation fault:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


double f(double a, double b, double* c) {
    *c = a + b;
}

int main() {
   vector<double> a ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};                     
   vector<double> b ={2,1,3,4,5,2,8,2};                    
   int size = a.size();
   vector<double> c(size);                               
   vector<thread*> threads(size);

   for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        thread* t = new thread(f, a[i], b[i], &c[i]);             
        threads.push_back(t);
   }

   for (vector<thread*>::iterator it = threads.begin(); it != threads.end();     it++) {
       (*it)->join();                                      
   }

   cout << "Vector c is: ";
   for (int i =0; i < size; ++i) {
       cout << c[i] << " ";                                 
   }
}
```

I know that the segmentation fault happens inside the for loop where the iterator is used, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Nothing is protecting access to c from concurrent access. You cannot just read/write variables from threads the same way you do in a single threaded program. You need to synchronize access by using a lock (like std::mutex) or by using std::atomic variables.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: I'm not sure, but I believe that no synchronization is required here. There is no concurrent write access anywhere.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
vector<thread*> threads(size);
```

Declaration creates a vector with `size` amount of default-initialized `thread*` objects which are `nullptr`.

Then with `push_back` you insert additional non-null objects but the null ones remain there, and you dereference them when iterating over vector at the end.

Answer (score 5):

You should change the `for` loop to read as below:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
  thread *t = new thread(f, a[i], b[i], &c[i]);
  threads[i] = t;
}
```

And before ending, you should `delete` your heap-allocated `thread`s.

```cpp
for (auto thread : threads)
  delete thread;
```

Even better is to simply use:

```cpp
vector<thread> threads(size);

for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  threads[i] = thread(f, a[i], b[i], &c[i]);

for (auto& thread : threads)
  thread.join();
```

By the way, you should pay attention to the compiler warnings. Change

```
double f(double a, double b, double *c) { *c = a + b; }
```

to

```
void f(double a, double b, double *c) { *c = a + b; }
```